# Why does this error keep popping up even though I clearly fixed it?

Tags: math-mode, errors, align

This is the code I have:

```
    \begin{align}
     \vec{l} \cdot \vec{n} & = \left \langle 1,2,3 \right \rangle$ \cdot \left \langle                  3,-3,1 \right \rangle \\
                           & = 3 - 6 + 3 \\
                           & = 0 \\
     \end{align}
```

Now for some reason, I keep getting this message:

```
 "Missing } inserted <inserted text> } \end{align}"
```

I clearly have completed my `}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `\rangle$`; simply delete the dollar sign. In your example, you don't really need `\left` and `\right`, so you can just say:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\vec{l} \cdot \vec{n} & = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle \cdot \langle 3,-3,1 \rangle \\
& = 3 - 6 + 3 \\
& = 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't TeX POINT that out? Instead of giving me misleading errors?

Comment: Wait why don't a need \left and \right?

Comment: @jak To your first question: when you get the error message, type `h`; then you'll get the message "I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing 2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear." Now type `2` and you'll get `<recently read> $`. So, in fact, TeX sees the problem ;-) (not as quickly as you've expected, but it sees it).

Comment: @jak to your second question: in this particular case there's no need for stretchable delimiters since the involved inner expressions do not extend vertically beyond the standard characters height.

Comment: @above what that does that mean lol? stretchable delimiters...? So when do I need it?

Comment: @jak stretchable delimiters will automatically adjust their (vertical) size according to the vertical size of the expression being delimited. In some circumstances you will require to use them, but in most cases you can use the alternative `\bigX`, `\BigX`, `\biggX`, and `\BiggX` family of commands. Search this site for questions about `\left`, `\right` and you'll find some discussions about whether and when to use them.