# $\displaystyle{#1}$ versus $\displaystyle#1$

Tags: plain-tex

In reading Appendix B of the TeXBook, I've noticed that Knuth consistently defines macros in Plain TeX with style switches of the form `$\displaystyle{#1}$` as opposed to simply `$\displaystyle#1$` (e.g., in mathpalette, in macros for use with mathpalette, in the math alignment macros, and more). I can't see any difference between these two, but the consistent use of the longer form suggests to me that there is a difference, especially since with non-style switch control sequences, Knuth often does just `\cseq#1` (where `\cseq` doesn't take any arguments). Is there any difference between these two forms?

EDIT: @Werner requested some examples. I've collected the following examples based just on pages 360 and 362 of the TeXBook:

- In every branch of the `\mathchoice` in `\mathpalette`:

  ```
  \def\mathpalette#1#2{\mathchoice{#1\displaystyle{#2}}%
    {#1\textstyle{#2}}{#1\scriptstyle{#2}}{#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}
  ```
- With `\scriptscriptstyle` inside `\root`:

  ```
  \def\root#1\of{\setbox\rootbox
    \hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}\mathpalette\r@@t}
  ```
- In `\mathph@nt`, which is intended for use with `\mathpalette`, so `#1`       is replaced by a style switch:

  ```
  \def\mathph@nt#1#2{\setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finph@nt}
  ```
- `\mathsm@sh` is similar to `\mathph@nt`.
- Twice in the template row of `\ialign` in `\eqalign` (the second instance is a little more interesting):

  ```
  \def\eqalign#1{\null\,\vcenter{\openup\jot\m@th
    \ialign{\strut\hfil$\displaystyle{##}$&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
        \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
  ```
- `\eqalignno` and `\leqalignno` are similar to `\eqalign`.
- `\displaylines` is *almost* a counterexample (but not quite due to the following `\hfil`), so perhaps it will help reveal something:

  ```
  \def\displaylines#1{\displ@y \tabskip\z@skip
    \halign{\hbox to\displaywidth{$\@lign\hfil\displaystyle##\hfil$}\crcr
      #1\crcr}}
  ```

Comment: This really depends on the context. For example, in math mode, there is a major difference between `a+b` and `a{+}b`. Also, there is sometimes a major difference in how `\mymacro#1` is presented compared to `\mymacro{#1}`; take [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/K3BP5Qac) as an example.

Comment: @Werner I should have been more specific. I tried to emphasize that there is nothing else surrounding the `\displaystyle{#1}` by explicitly writing the dollar signs. I know that `{+}` causes `+` to become a mathord, but I can't see how that matters if nothing is surrounding it. Also, when I wrote `\mymacro`, I was assuming `\mymacro` took no arguments, just like how `\XXXstyle` has no arguments.

Comment: Well then, be more specific. Show where/how it is used in your TeXBook references so we can examine what the use-case might be.

Comment: @Werner I did reference a few examples in my original post, but I've edited my post to directly include some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare `$\displaystyle 1\over2$` with `$\displaystyle{1\over2}$`.

The macros which use `\displaystyle{#1}` allow to use `\macro{1\over2}` and this will print correctly.

Answer (score 4):

note that `\displaystyle` never takes an argument so the difference is between `${...}$` and `$...$`  `\over` as wipet says but also `{...}`  acts like a box, it freezes all white space at its natural size and prevents line breaking.

[image]

```
Compare $\displaystyle 1 + 2$ with $\displaystyle{1 + 2}$ \break here
\bye
```

---

A comment on the `\displaylines` example you added in the question, it is not braced there probably to allow glue to stretch (as in the l=l and r=r lines below) but not bracing has a bad effect on `\over` as shown, unless you explicitly add braces to correct.

[image]

```
wipet:
Compare $\displaystyle 1\over2$ with $\displaystyle{1\over2}$

\bigskip


displaylines
$$\displaylines{
a=b\cr
x=y\cr
l=l\hfill\cr
\hfill r=r\cr
1 \over 2 \cr
{1 \over 2}\cr
}
$$

\bye
```

Comment: What you're saying here implicitly recognizes that LaTeX has defined `\frac` to replace `\over`, which in plain TeX *does definitely* require the braces although the reason is not that what is inside them is an argument.  This is a *very* significant difference between plain and LaTeX, and deserves to be highlighted.  (And probably documented better.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it doesn't require braces (although normally you need them as normally the fraction isn't the whole expression) , the case in the question `$ 1 \over 2 $`  works perfectly well without braces. You only need to add braces if you want to add `\displaystyle` as `$\displaystyle 1 \over 2$` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Of course, `${1 \over 2} abc$` needs braces whether or not `\displaystyle` is used.  Maybe the lack of understanding should be laid on the TeXbook for not saying why the braces are there.  (Although I haven't gone back to check the TeXbook, and may be mistaken.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes but I think you missed that this question is specifically asking why the macros brace _the whole expression_ It is not asking about `\over` at all, really.

Comment: No argument there.  But I still think it's not well enough appreciated that input braces are rather overloaded, and the overloading gets more complicated as LaTeX progresses.